How do I set a password for a Custom User model inside the Django admin page?
I have defined a custom user model using AbstractBaseUser class. Below is the implementation for your reference.
#models.py

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, firstname, lastname, contact, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('You must provide an email address')
        if not contact:
            raise ValueError('You must provide a contact number')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, contact=contact)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, firstname, lastname, contact, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, firstname, lastname, contact, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'contact']

    objects = UserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.firstname or not self.lastname or not self.contact or not self.email or not self.password:
            raise ValueError('All required fields must be provided')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + '. ' + self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

Everything works well apart from setting password for a new user or updating same for an existing user in Django's native Admin page. While setting password, it sets passwords in a plain text rather than hashing it.
Here's my admin.py code.
#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.site_header = 'ROI Administration'
admin.site.site_title = 'ROI | Admin Panel'
admin.site.index_title = 'ROI Databases'

class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    readonly_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'last_login']
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'contact', 'last_login', 'created_at', 'is_staff', 'is_admin', 'password']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(Users, UsersAdmin)

Refer below the screenshot.

How do I resolve this?

I did some research and finally solved it. I created CustomUserAdmin and CustomUserChangeForm in admin.py file.
#admin.py

from .models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm, AdminPasswordChangeForm
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    ordering = ['id']
    readonly_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'last_login']
    list_display = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'contact', 'is_staff', 'is_admin']
    fieldsets = (
        ('Credentials', {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('firstname', 'lastname', 'contact')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_admin')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'created_at')})
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'contact', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_admin'),
        }),
    )

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = []

    def change_password(self, request, user_id, form_url=''):
        user = self.get_object(request, user_id)
        if not self.has_change_permission(request, user):
            raise PermissionDenied

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return self.response_change(request, user)
        else:
            form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(user)

        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': list(form.base_fields)})]
        admin_form = admin.helpers.AdminForm(form, fieldsets, {})

        context = {
            'title': f'Change password: {user.email}',
            'adminForm': admin_form,
            'form_url': form_url,
            'form': form,
            'is_popup': "_popup" in request.POST or "_popup" in request.GET,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': user,
            'save_as': False,
            'show_save': True,
            **self.admin_site.each_context(request),
        }

        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/auth/user/change_password.html', context)

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.urls import path
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path(
                '<user_id>/password/',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.change_password),
                name='auth_user_password_change',
            ),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

admin.site.register(Users, CustomUserAdmin)

It solves the problem.

You need to use the specific UserAdmin class like this admin.UserAdmin. That should fix your issue

Can you assist explicitly on its usage?

If you just change this line you should be fine: class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): -> class UsersAdmin(admin. UserAdmin):

I tried with above. I then get below errors since I have custom fields in user model as shown in the problem. Here's what the error says.
ERRORS:
<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'groups', which is not a field of 'app.Users'.
<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[1]' refers to 'user_permissions', which is not a field of 'app.Users'.
...
...


Then you can manually adjust those filter to not include those fields: filter_horizontal = []

What file do I change in and what code part do I change in?

You can adjust your UsersAdmin, just set filter_horizontal = [] in that class.
